# How to set radio button to checked when i click on list item

Tags: android, listview, android-radiobutton

I am having a problem with my listview ( 2 textview and 1 radio button).

**The problem:
My idea is that the user clicks on the item in the listview and the radio button gets checked automatically.**

I have been searching for a while, but I can't get the radio button to work.

My XML

```
   <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rdBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false" />
```

My Adapter

```
    r = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rdBtn);
        r.setChecked(selectedPosition == position);
        r.setTag(position);
        r.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //r.setChecked(true);
                Toast.makeText(context, InformationActivity.result,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                selectedPosition = (Integer) view.getTag();
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();

            }
        });
        return convertView;
```

I tried

```
r.setChecked(true);
```

inside my activity class and the first click worked, but the second chooses a different item on the listview.

I hope some of you can help me.
Thanks

Comment: just a blind shot - `r.requestLayout();` after setting to checked?

Comment: @cyborg86pl Don't work for me :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution here:
[How to check checkbox on clicking an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19497377/how-to-check-checkbox-on-clicking-an-image)

```
        searchList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                int position, long arg3) {

            LinearLayout item_view = (LinearLayout) view;
            final RadioButton itemcheck = (RadioButton) item_view
                    .findViewById(R.id.rdBtn);

            if (itemcheck.isChecked()) {
                itemcheck.setChecked(true);
            } else {
                itemcheck.setChecked(false);
            }

            itemcheck.setChecked(true);


<RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rdBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve, but maybe this would help?

```
r.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            // radio button is checked
        } else {
            // radio button is not checked
        }
    }
});
```

*Edit.*

Assuming `list` is your `ListView`, you could do the following:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        r.setChecked(true); // true to make r checked, false otherwise.
    }
});
```

Comment: I want the radio button to automatically check it self, when the user clicks an item om the listview

Comment: I have already used the r.setChecked(true); and it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

you can set the list setOnItemClickListener.

Answer (score 0):

You should set OnClick Listener for 'convertview' and toggle radioButton as follows-

```
 convertview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           radioButton.toggle()
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried that, but it just checks random radio buttons and toast one item

Comment: you should use array for maintaining state of checked items

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10023999/android-save-checkbox-state-in-listview

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using below functionality,

1.Use radiogroup.clearCheck();
  To clear the all the checked state of radio buttons in listview scrolling.

2.Maintain the checked state of each radio button in a list.
  If radio button checked state is changed update the value in list.

Answer (score -1):

You may use checktextview inside the listview and set the type of checktextview to look like radiobutton or use background image for checktextview check so that it look like radio button.Hope this helps you

Comment: How do I do that? Does that mean that I have to change my layout or just insert the checktextview?

Comment: @camo:you have custom listview item.so you can use only checktextview for listview item as you can set text to checktextview and the right side you will see checkbox.you need to change the style of checkbox to radiobutton.

Comment: Can I set 2 textviews in one item, by using the checkedtextview? and how? I have been searching for the answer for a while now :)

Comment: yes use this link for example http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/ custom listview with custom item you need to use textview then checktextview in item.xml file then set text to textview and checktextview and on listitem click listeneer change the checktextview check.Hope this helps you